# Migracion Laravel no permite llave foranea nullable

Tags: sql, laravel

necesito crear una llave foranea que pueda ser nullable, en la documentacion de laravel dan el siguiente ejemplo.

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')
      ->nullable()
      ->constrained();
```

Yo estoy colocando lo siguiente:

```
 $table->foreignId('municipio_id')->references('id')->on('municipios')->nullable()->constrained();
```

Al cargar la migración me queda todo las restricciones menos que pueda ser null, que podrá ser? Gracias

Comment: Y si lo ponés antes de los otros métodos? `$table->foreignId('municipio_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('municipios')->constrained();`

Comment: Si señor, muchas gracias. El orden si importa y ya funciona, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El método `foreignId` crea una columna equivalente a `UNSIGNED BIGINT`, mientras que el método de restricción `constrained` usará convenciones para determinar la tabla y el nombre de la columna a la que se hace referencia. Si el nombre de su tabla no coincide con las convenciones de Laravel, puede especificar el nombre de la tabla pasándolo como un argumento al método `constrained`.

Además, cualquier modificador de columna adicional debe llamarse antes de los método de referencia y restricción:

```
$table->foreignId('municipio_id')
      ->nullable()
      ->constrained('municipios');
```

Ref: [Foreign Key Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).